# jQuery fixed item when scrolling reset when at top?

Tags: jquery, offset, scrolltop

I have a navigation menu in the header at the top of the screen that changes color and adds fixed positioning when the user scrolls down the screen to keep it in place but I would like this to reset to the original style when the user scrolls back to the top.

My current code to add the fixed class is:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $("header").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
            $("header").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            $("header").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

But I would like this to remove the class when the user scrolls to the top again which it currently isn't doing.

Regards,

Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note to future visitors, I've had this issue before, but realised that it was actually the browser resetting the scroll position and not the script.

Some browsers will try to reset the scroll position when reloading a page - so beware of using the browsers refresh to reload the page when testing scripts involving window scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Your not selecting your tags correctly.  Take a look at this jsfiddle, it should solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/aEJMF/

It may not be exactly what you need but its a good start

Comment: Thanks for your message, my current one works fine with the tag using just header as jQuery recognises this as it is not a class or id I just want to get the item to reset when it scroll back to the top. Thanks for your help anyway.